# Fragments of paper

Tags: java

The exercise is explained in the comments. Do you have any suggestion?

```
package com.atreceno.it.javanese.attic;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Imagine you have several copies of the same page of text. Someone rips each
 * page up into fragments. Write a program to reassemble a given set of text
 * fragments into their original sequence. The program should have a main method
 * accepting the path to a text file containing text fragments separated by a
 * semicolon. Each line in the file is a different test case.
 * 
 * @author atreceno
 * 
 */
public class Defragmenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(reassemble(line));
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assemble the fragments in the correct order.
     * 
     * @param line
     *            String containing the fragments of the document.
     * @return the line in the correct order.
     */
    private static String reassemble(String line) {

        // Each line contains text fragments separated by a semicolon.
        String[] fragments = line.split(";");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fragments));

        // Sort the fragments by size
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o2.length() - o1.length();
            }
        });

        // Pick up the first fragment
        String text = list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);

        // Start the algorithm
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int max = 0;
            int idx = 0;
            int match = 0;
            int m = 0;
            int n = 0;
            for (int j = list.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                String findMe = list.get(j);
                m = text.length();
                n = findMe.length();
                for (int k = 1 - findMe.length(); k < text.length(); k++) {
                    if (k < 0) { // Prefix
                        int l = n + k;
                        if (text.regionMatches(0, findMe, -k, l)) {
                            if (l > max) {
                                idx = k;
                                max = l;
                                match = j;
                            }
                        }
                    } else { // Suffix
                        int l = k + n <= m ? n : m - k;
                        if (text.regionMatches(k, findMe, 0, l)) {
                            if (l > max) {
                                idx = k;
                                max = l;
                                match = j;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (idx < 0) { // Prefix
                text = list.get(match).substring(0, -idx) + text;
            } else if (idx > m - list.get(match).length()) { // Suffix
                text = text + list.get(match).substring(m - idx);
            }
            list.remove(match);
        }
        return text;
    }

}
```

Comment: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is really good and very well written.  I think that's why you haven't received a response; not much to critique!  You have good comments, good style, pretty much good everything.  I wish I saw code like this in my production environment.

The only thing I noticed that you might clean your code up a bit is this part:

```
int max = 0;
int idx = 0;
int match = 0;
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
```

You can shorten this long block of variable declarations as the following.  Makes the code look a bit cleaner.

```
int max = 0, idx = 0, match = 0, m = 0, n = 0;
```

Also, if possible, could you give the variables better names?  The first three are fairly self-explanatory, but once you get into all your random letters, it gets pretty hard to follow what you're trying to do in your code.  For example:

```
int l = k + n <= m ? n : m - k;
```

Without having written the code, this statement takes awhile to figure out.  It would go a long way to have meaningful variable names rather than random letters.  Java is supposed to be verbose, so don't be afraid to make it so.

I won't say I understand what your code is doing with 100% certainty, but you can see how something like this is a bit more understandable, hopefully:

```
int length = lookBack + findMeLength <= trueLength ? findMeLength : trueLength - lookBack
```

But seriously, very high quality code!

Comment: If you figured out their meaning, could you suggest better names for them?

Comment: Thanks for adding names. It's the fact I couldn't understand it (because of the variable names) that made me not want to review it, and it's the reason I can't call it "high quality code". IMO source code should be written for humans to understand.

Comment: @ChrisW Haha, yeah.  But if the names of variables in those tightly-nested loops is the only thing to critique, still not very bad. :)